# Problema com width:100% em imagem responsiva no bootstrap 3 para dispositivos mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

estou com um problema que a princípio é bem básico, mas já tentei tudo que é jeito e não está funcionando

O problema só ocorre ao abrir o site no smartphone.. se eu simular a resolução no navegador do PC ele funciona normal..

Vejam a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que há uma margem lateral à direita.. eu preciso que a imagem e a logo fiquem 100% da tela.. esse problema só ocorre no smartphone estou usando o EDGE do windows phone 10.

estou usando bootstrap 3 e já utilizo os meta-tags abaixo:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

no html o código está assim:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                <h1 class="logo"><img class="img-responsive" src="logo.png" alt="logo"></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 no-gutter">
                <img src="maroon5.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

meu css está assim:

```
.no-gutter { padding: 0;}
```

já tentei colocar width:100%, padding:0 !important.. e outras coisas.. mas nada tira essa margem lateral..

alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Já tentasse colocar este teu css dentro de um @media, para aplicar a regra para os tamanhos específicos para dispositivos mobile?

Comment: Já tentei sim.. se eu tiro essa regra de css a imagem centraliza, deixando uma pequena margem nas laterais.. contudo eu preciso que ela se estique ficando como width:100%.. mas não tá rolando

Comment: Interessante que no Browser Edge do meu celular o site nem abre, ele dá erro 501.. no computador, mesmo no internet explorer, abre perfeitamente sem erros

Comment: E o que esta antes de <div class="container-fluid">?

Comment: Coloquei no ar pra vcs me ajudarem.. o site é esse aqui http://novo.sitesparabandas.com.br/ é só inspecionar o código fonte.. antes do container-fluid vem uma header com id #p_inicial.. e antes vem o main navigation.. scripts, tags..  no pc abre de boa.. no windows phone dá erro 501.. e em outros browsers mobile as imagems não atingem o width:100%

Comment: Cara é um windowsPhone poucas pessoas utilizam o mesmo, eu acredito que se você resolver o problema apenas pra sistemas mais utilizados não vá influenciar tanto na visualização dos usuários, por exemplo já testou e viu se o problema persiste nos navegadores a seguir: Opera, Mozilla e Chrome

Comment: Não sei se influencia,mas esta parte '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://novo.sitesparabandas.com.br/layout/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://novo.sitesparabandas.com.br/layout/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://novo.sitesparabandas.com.br/layout/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://novo.sitesparabandas.com.br/layout/js/sys.js"></script>' teria que estar no final da página antes do js do bootstrap acho.